# java substring raising an exception

Tags: java, android

So i want to extract few characters from a string and then display it on Textview like this:

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
  Cursor crsr = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

  startManagingCursor(crsr);

  String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body",
      "type" };

  String address = "";
  String msg = "";

  ArrayList<String> conversations = new ArrayList<String>();

  if (crsr.getCount() > 0) {
    while (crsr.moveToNext()) {
      address = crsr.getString(crsr.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
      msg = crsr.getString(crsr.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
      msg = msg.substring(1, 30) + "..."; // THIS CAUSES FATAL ERROR          
      conversations.add(address + "\n\n" + msg);          
    }
  }
```

It is pretty simple to use `substring` but i can't get why it is giving error and showing fatal errors, here is trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity......
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; regionStart=1; regionLength=29
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at com.sarfraznawaz.cleansms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
E/AndroidRuntime(14023):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong with the line?

```
msg = msg.substring(1, 30) + "...";
```

Thanks

Comment: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; regionStart=1; regionLength=29`

Comment: Without checking the string length why are you performing substring operation??

Comment: @kalyanpvs: Because it is `LOGIC` error :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from your log its clearly mentioned, your **string length is not 30**.

So just check for its length before using subString.

```
 if(msg.length()>=30)
 msg = msg.substring(1, 30) + "..."; 
 else 
 msg = msg.substring(1, msg.length()) + "...";   // Also check here string length is more than 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your message `msg` is not that long (it is less than 30 chars long). This is the problem.